# Adding animation in redux

Tags: css, animation, redux

I am currently building a small web page using react-redux. In my page I am rendering two containers. One container has a button that on clicking causes a change in the state and as a result the content in the other container also changes e.g initially there is a div container with text hello my name is rishi bhatia. As soon as I click on the button the a separate div container with 4 links replaces the previously displayed div container. What are the possible ways in which I can add animations when the content in the container changes. All I am doing is displaying different div containers on state change.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps). Here you can define your animation when component receive props playing with state.

Even if your component is just presentational id doesn't mean it cannot use state for graphical purposes.